# Search failing?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I can't seem to search for anything on BG.SE. I always get 0 results even for searches that I know should yield questions (e.g. because I'm searching for a question that I already know is there).

Searching for "Jund" or "Diplomacy" generates 0 results even though there are questions with those words in the title.

Tag-searches still seem to work correctly.

Comment: Yikes! Something's broken. I see the same behaviour.

Comment: I tried search on a smattering of other sites, beta and non-beta, logged in and not, and they all seem to be fine.

Comment: @ire_and_curses Wait, sorry, I'm confused: so BG.SE *is* broken but other SEs are unaffected?

Comment: So it would seem...

Comment: Searching by tag (e.g. `[diplomacy]`) still seems to be functional.

Comment: One of the team is looking into it: [Searching on Board and Card Games is broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171281/searching-on-board-and-card-games-is-broken)

Comment: I just searched on "diplomacy" (the word, not the tag) and got six pages of results.  (Firefox 18.0.1, WinXP)

Comment: Works for me now, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just to close the loop: this appears to have been fixed sometime during the day. Hooray!

You can find more technical details in [this explanation from Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173290/132073).